# Why do I get VMExtensionProvisioningError. Failed to download all specified files?

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-rm

I am trying to provision a vm and promote it to domain controller through a powershell script by running through customscriptextension of AzureRM, but it is giving an unexpected network close error. I am importing the powershell script from a github repository to be run post deployment Here is the code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~>1.44.0"
}

# Create a new resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name     = "myTFResourceGroup"
    location = "eastus2"

    tags = {
        Environment = "Terraform Getting Started"
        Team = "DevOps"   
    }
}
variable "prefix" {
  default = "vmtrial"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-publicip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name


  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                      = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.main.id

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.main.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "*******************"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "main" {
  name                  = "vhds"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}



resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
   delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
   delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    vhd_uri       = "${azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.main.name}/myosdisk1.vhd"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    #managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "*********"
    admin_password = "*************"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config{
    provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  tags = {
    Owner = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_machine_name = azurerm_virtual_machine.main.name
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"./dservicerole.ps1; exit 0;\""
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": [
          "https://github.com/Aditya0311/Scripts/blob/master/dservicerole.ps1"
        ]
    }
  SETTINGS
}
```

This is the error that I receive:

Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'hostname'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "

Why do I get VMExtensionProvisioningError. Failed to download all specified files?

Comment: have you found any solution, so far?

Comment: no, I am having to do it manually in the test environment right now